# How to route directly to a Laravel Backpack controller action

Tags: laravel-backpack

How can you bypass the CRUD:: routes (ex: Route::crud('profile', 'ProfileCrudController');) and go directly to an action such as Route::get('profile/create', 'ProfileCrudController@create');?  Trying any of the routes outside of the crud:: route setup gives different errors for each route.  Even simply routing directly to Route::get('profile/', 'ProfileCrudController@index');  throws errors for in_array().

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, Backpack uses CrudControllers to load routes. So if your CrudControllers are not error-free, other routes will also suffer, and show errors. This is one downside of loading routes in the controller - your controllers should not have PHP errors. I'd recommend you debug the `in_array()` problem you have, and fix it. But if you can't do that, or would rather stay away from the way Backpack loads its routes, there's the solution below.

What `Route::crud('profile', 'ProfileCrudController');` does is that it calls [CrudController::setupRoutes](https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/CRUD/blob/master/src/app/Http/Controllers/CrudController.php#L62), which in turn calls all methods on that CrudController that look something like this - `setupOperationNameRoutes()` - methods whose only purpose are to load the route for an operation (ex: setupCreateRoutes, setupUpdateRoutes, setupDeleteRoutes).

If for some reason you are unhappy with the routes added by the `Route::crud()` macro, it's perfectly to delete that line, and manually write all routes your CrudPanel needs. Your CrudController uses a trait for each each operation that can be performed inside the admin panel. Each operation trait has a `setupOperationNameRoutes()` method, that clearly defines what routes it needs.

You can:

- go through each operation your CrudController uses (ex: `\Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\Operations\DeleteOperation`);
- inside that file, see the routes needed by that operation (ex: `Route::delete('profile/{id}', ['as' => 'profile.destroy', 'uses' => 'ProfileCrudController@destroy', 'operation' => 'delete']);`
- hardcode that route into your `routes/backpack/custom.php` file, or anywhere else you'd like to hold that route;

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I am resuming this with another use case months later.  Essentially the original post is an attempt to do the following in an multi-tenant system using Backpack.  If the user is a superadmin, let them view all records on the List view in Backpack.  If the user is not a superadmin, ONLY show their record and decide to show a Create route or an Update route in Backpack.  So essentially, a non-admin can only either create 1 single record, or edit that record if it exists while superadmin can view all tenant records. Unable to figure out how to route this in Backpack. thanks!